# How do I add values to an array

Tags: c#, lua

I am currently working on a programming language, and my friend asked me to convert it to a console application and, so far it hasn't been going well

```
if (input.Contains(""))
{
    string name = input.Substring(0, 3);
    string value = input.Substring(4);
    Console.WriteLine("Name:" + name + " " +  "Value:" + value);
    vars[Convert.ToInt32(name)] = value;
}
```

The line that says `vars[Convert.ToInt32(name)] = value;` has been giving me errors
when I run it the first 3 lines above it work this is an example of what I would type in the console `str Hello` and it would print `Name:str Value:Hello` but then it stops the program and shows me this error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I'm not to familiar with this error but if you have ever programmed in Lua this is what im trying to accomplish

```
elseif line:match("^int") then
    local n, v = line:match("^int (.+) = (%d+)")
    vars[n] = v
```

I always had a problem with arrays in C#, so if you could please tell me whats wrong it would help me a lot, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(name)` if name is not numeric (which most likely it isn't, given the variable name `name`) within the range of `int` then the format is incorrect.

Comment: What is the expected value for `Convert.ToInt32(name)`?

Comment: Note that `input.Contains("")` will always return `true` (or throw an exception if `input` is `null`).

Comment: If that's regular expressions in your lua code you might want to use the [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you actually want a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to hold a key-value pair of name and value. You can only use an `int` for an index on an array, so a dictionary allows you to use string values.

```
var inputDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
if (input.Contains(""))
{
    string name = input.Substring(0, 3);
    string value = input.Substring(4);
    Console.WriteLine("Name:" + name + " " +  "Value:" + value);
    inputDictionary.Add(name, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can have a HashTable like below

```
        Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
        if (input.Contains(string.Empty))
        {
            hashTable.Add(input.Substring(0, 3), input.Substring(4));
        }
```